# Intersection of ranges of projections

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, projection-matrices

Let $A$ be a unital $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra and $p,\,q$ non-zero projections in $A$. Consider two faithful representations of $A$ on Hilbert spaces $\mathsf{H}_1,\,\mathsf{H}_2$.

Is it possible for the intersections of the ranges of the projections to be zero in one representation and non-zero in the other?

Comment: Why do you need two projections to ask this questions? It seems that it is a question about only one projection.

Comment: @Frederik the title gave the correct question... edited to reflect this.

Comment: So you can let $p$ be the identity and ask the same question for one projection.

Comment: @Frederik I'm not quite putting the two sticks together - that assumption on $p$ makes either both or neither intersections zero...but I cannot see how that assumption is the basis for arguing the phenomenon above can never happen. (PS I hadn't originally assumed the algebra unital but can for my needs so added it).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $(e_n)$.  Let $p\in B(H)$ be the projection onto the span of the vectors $e_{2n}$ and let $q\in B(H)$ be the projection onto the span of the vectors $e_{2n}+2^{-n}e_{2n+1}$.

Note now that $p-q$ is a compact operator (it can be written as the norm limit of the finite rank operators $p_n-q_n$ where $p_n$ and $q_n$ are the corresponding projections onto the spans of just the first $n$ of the basis vectors).  So, $p$ and $q$ are equal and nonzero projections in the quotient $B(H)/K(H)$.  Now take a faithful representation of $B(H)/K(H)$ on some Hilbert space $H'$, so $p$ and $q$ act by the same nonzero projection on $H'$.  Then $B(H)$ has a natural faithful representation on $H\oplus H'$, and the ranges of $p$ and $q$ have nontrivial intersection in this representation.  However, in the faithful representation on just $H$, the ranges of $p$ and $q$ have trivial intersection.

Comment: Beautiful. The Calkin representation is probably the only reasonable way to go, as any normal representation will satisfy $\pi(p\wedge q)=\pi(p)\wedge \pi(q)$.

Comment: Thank you. I have an example also but feared I made a mistake. Take the universal C*-algebra generated by two projections. There is a faithful representation construction of Pederson and in that representation p and q have trivial intersection. The state that takes both p and q to one, the GNS construction of that should give a cyclic vector in the intersection of the ranges... I think

Comment: Interesting to consider convergence of sequence of (pq)^n in light of this.

Comment: Is there a good reference to learn about more representation-dependent properties (that might be assumed determined by the C*algebra)?

Comment: @JPMcCarthy: Probably but I am not the right person to ask, I'm afraid.