# Eigenvalues and (Singleton)-Borel Functional Calculus

Tags: representation-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, spectral-theory, c-star-algebras

I am having some confusion that I hope people might be able to help me with. To be concrete I will use two (isomorphic) $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebras.

---

The first, $A_1$, is the $\mathrm{C}^*$-group algebra of the (amenable) infinite dihedral group $D_\infty$ with order two generators $u$ and $v$ (it is isomorphic to the free product of cyclic groups) $C_2\star C_2$. Consider it represented by the regular representation as $\pi_1(\mathrm{C}^*(D_\infty))\subset B(\ell^2(D_\infty))$. The particular element I am interested in is the sum of two projections:

$$a_1:=\frac12\delta^e+\frac12 \delta^u+\frac12\delta^ e+\frac12 \delta^v=\delta^e+\frac{1}{2}\delta^u+\frac{1}{2}\delta^v.$$

I understand (via the isomorphism with $A_2$ below that the spectrum  $\sigma(a_1)=[0,2]$.

---

> **Question 1: is one an eigenvalue of $\pi_1(a_1)$? If yes what is an eigenvector?**

---

The second $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $A_2$ is the universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra generated by projections $p$ and $q$. [It is isomorphic](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/12283) that it is isomorphic to $A_3$, where $A_3$ is the $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra:
$$A_3:=\left\{f\in C([0,1],M_2(\mathbb{C})):f(0) \text{ and }f(1)\text{ are diagonal}\right\}.$$

There is an isomorphism that carries $p$ and $q$, respectively, to
$$p(x)=\left(\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{array}\right)\quad \text{ and }\quad q(x)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}x & \sqrt{x(1-x)} \\ \sqrt{x(1-x)} & 1-x\end{array}\right).$$

This can be represented $\pi_2(A_3)\subset B(L^2([0,1])\oplus L^2([0,1]))$.

Consider
$$a_2:=x\mapsto p(x)+q(x)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}1+x & \sqrt{x(1-x)} \\ \sqrt{x(1-x)} & 1-x\end{array}\right).$$

The determinant of $a_2(x)-\lambda I_{\pi(A_3)}$ is $\lambda^2-2\lambda-x+1$ which is an issue when $\lambda=1\pm\sqrt{x}$, and so the spectrum $\sigma(a_2)=[0,2]$. As far as I can see it $\pi_2(a_2)$ has no eigenvalues at all.

---

> **Question 2: Is this correct --- $\pi_2(a_2)$ has no eigenvalues?**

---

This leads onto a third question (possibly giving an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3986313/representation-dependent-properties-of-mathrmc-algebras)).

> **Question 3: Unless I am mistaken, the spectrum of an element $a$ of a $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra $A$ is the same in every faithful
> representation of $A$. Is it possible for a $\lambda\in \sigma(a)$ to
> be an eigenvalue in one representation $\pi(A)$ but not in another
> $\pi'(A)$?**

---

Final question. Take a faithful representation of $A_1$, $A_2$ or $A_3$ (which I think are all isomorphic) and consider, as appropriate, the $a_1$ or $a_2$ given above. Let us call it by $a$. Is there any particular relation between an element of the spectrum $\lambda\in\sigma(a)$ being an eigenvalue or not, and the bounded operator given by the Borel functional calculus, $\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}(a)$? Is this $\mathbf{1}_{\{\lambda\}}$ a projection if $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue?

---

In particular,

> **Question 4: For either $a_1$ or $a_2$ above, if it is true that $1\in\sigma(a)$ is not an eigenvalue, is $\mathbf{1}_{\{1\}}(a)$ equal
> to zero?**

---

I fully expect there to be some errors/confusions above and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Do you really have algebras $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$.  I see only two algebras defined.

Comment: @Ruy $A_1:=\mathrm{C}^*(D_\infty)$, $A_2:=\mathrm{C}^*(p,q,1:p,q\text{ projections})$ (universal $\mathrm{C}^*$-algebra, forgot to define this clearly), and $A_3$ is in the question.

Comment: Regarding question 3, think about the representation of $C([0,1])$ on $L^2[0,1]\oplus \mathbb C$, sending each $f$ to
$M_f\oplus f(0)$, where $M_f$ the multiplication operator.

Comment: Whenever $T$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, one has that $1_{\{\lambda \}}(T)$ is the projection onto the
eigenspace $\text{Ker}(T-\lambda )$.  So, yes, $1_{\{\lambda \}}(T)$ is nonzero iff $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue.

Comment: @Ruy I am also thinking about (in relation to your second comment) $\mathrm{C}^*(p,q)\subset B(L^2([0,1])\oplus L^2([0,1])\oplus \ell^2(V))$, where $V$ is Klein four-group, and $p=(\delta^e+\delta^{(0,1)})/2$ and $q=(\delta^e+\delta^{(0,1)})/2$ (on that summand), then in that representation it does have eigenvalues.

Comment: Agreed.  I guess that whenever $A$ is a C*-algebra,  $a\in  A$ is self adjoint, and $\lambda \in \sigma (a)$, there exista a faithful
representation $\pi $  of $A$ such that $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $\pi (a)$.  Start by considering a character on $C^*(1,a)$
sending $a$ to $\lambda $, extend this to a representation of $A$ (on a larger Hilbert space) and add on any faithful
representation of $A$.

Comment: Regarding Q2, I think you are correct.   For almost all $x$, the matrix $a_2(x)-\lambda$ is invertible, so a potential
eigenvector will have to vanish a.e.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a few answers.  I'll be happy to elaborate more upon request.

---

> **Question 2: Is this correct --- $\pi_2(a_2)$ has no eigenvalues?**

I think you are correct. For almost all $x$, the matrix $a_2(x)-\lambda $ is invertible, so a potential eigenvector will have to vanish a.e.

> **Question 3: Unless I am mistaken, the spectrum of an element $a$ of a C$^*$-algebra $A$ is the same in every faithful
> representation of $A$. Is it possible for a $\lambda\in \sigma(a)$ to
> be an eigenvalue in one representation $\pi(A)$ but not in another
> $\pi'(A)$?**

Whenever $A$ is a C*-algebra, $a\in A$ is self adjoint, and $\lambda \in \sigma (A)$, there exista a faithful representation $\pi $ of $A$
such that $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $\pi (a)$.  To prove it, start by considering a character on $C^*(1, a)$  sending $a$ to $\lambda $, extend this to a representation of $A$ (on a larger Hilbert space) and add on any faithful representation of $A$.

> **Question 4: For either $a_1$ or $a_2$ above, if it is true that $1\in\sigma(a)$ is not an eigenvalue, is ${1}_{\{1\}}(a)$ equal
> to zero?**

Whenever $T$ is a bounded self-adjoint operator on a Hilbert space, one has that $1_{\{\lambda \}}(T)$ is the projection onto the eigenspace $\text{Ker}(T−\lambda )$. So, yes, $1_{\{\lambda \}}(T)$ is nonzero iff $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue.